# PHP get array of search terms from string

Tags: php, search

Is there an easy way to parse a string for search terms including negative terms?

```
'this -that "the other thing" -"but not this" "-positive"'
```

would change to

```
array(
  "positive" => array(
    "this",
    "the other thing",
    "-positive"
  ),
  "negative" => array(
    "that",
    "but not this"
  )
)
```

so those terms could be used to search.

Comment: What you want to change exactly? I don't understand what you have and what you want to change?!? Please show how the array looks at the start and how it should look at the end!

Comment: I want to separate search terms from a string and save them to an array. In my example the top code block would be the string input and the bottom code block would be the array output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below will parse your query string and split it up into positive and negative search terms.

```
// parse the query string
$query = 'this -that "-that" "the other thing" -"but not this" ';
preg_match_all('/-*"[^"]+"|\S+/', $query, $matches);

// sort the terms
$terms = array(
    'positive' => array(),    
    'negative' => array(),
);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    if ('-' == $match[0]) {
        $terms['negative'][] = trim(ltrim($match, '-'), '"');
    } else {
        $terms['positive'][] = trim($match, '"');
    }
}

print_r($terms);
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [positive] => Array
        (
            [0] => this
            [1] => -that
            [2] => the other thing
        )

    [negative] => Array
        (
            [0] => that
            [1] => but not this
        )
)
```

Comment: it fails on "-that" which is not the same as -that. It should be positive (hyphen)that

Comment: @UziTech Sorry, that term was not in your OP so I did not take that one into account. I have updated the code now to support it.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the same thing I have created a gist for PHP and JavaScript

https://gist.github.com/UziTech/8877a79ebffe8b3de9a2

```
function getSearchTerms($search) {
    $matches = null;
    preg_match_all("/-?\"[^\"]+\"|-?'[^']+'|\S+/", $search, $matches);

    // sort the terms
    $terms = [
        "positive" => [],
        "negative" => []
    ];
    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $match) {
        $negative = ("-" === $match[0]);
        if ($negative) {
            $match = substr($match, 1);
        }
        if (($match[0] === '"' && substr($match, -1) === '"') || ($match[0] === "'" && substr($match, -1) === "'")) {
            $match = substr($match, 1, strlen($match) - 2);
        }
        if ($negative) {
            $terms["negative"][] = $match;
        } else {
            $terms["positive"][] = $match;
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```