# Validate password policy with PHP preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a password using preg_match and RegEx but it doesn't seem to work. What I want to do is: ensure the password meets the following minimal conditions:
- Contains mixed case letters
- Contains atleast one number
- The rest can be anything as long as the two conditions above are met.

I've tried the following RegEx but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])
```

I've had other previous easier RegEx'es like: `[A-Za-z0-9]` but without success. I'm checking if `preg_match($string, $pattern) == 0` (meaning the pattern doesn't match => validation fails) but it always returns 0. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a starting anchor to your regex,

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])
```

OR

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).*
```

Example:

```
$yourstring = 'Ab';
$regex = '~^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])~m';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring)) {
    echo 'Yes! It matches!';
    } 
else { 
echo 'No, it fails';
     }   // No, it fails
```

Answer (score 3):

I always try to avoid regex if it's possible so I took a different approach to the problem. The below code will test the password for at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one digit.

```
function isValidPassword($password)
{
    $hasUppercase = false;
    $hasLowercase = false;
    $hasDigit     = false;

    foreach (str_split($password) as $char)
    {
        $charAsciiValue = ord($char);

        if ($charAsciiValue >= ord('A') && $charAsciiValue <= ord('Z')) {
            $hasUppercase = true;
        }

        if ($charAsciiValue >= ord('a') && $charAsciiValue <= ord('z')) {
            $hasLowercase = true;
        }

        if ($charAsciiValue >= ord('0') && $charAsciiValue <= ord('9')) {
            $hasDigit = true;
        }
    }

    return $hasUppercase && $hasLowercase && $hasDigit;
}

var_dump(isValidPassword('Ab9c'));
var_dump(isValidPassword('abc'));
```

### Output

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: Do you own shares in a keyboard company, or is there some other reason for avoiding something that is so perfectly suited to this task?

Comment: @rjdown My opinion is that in general it takes more mental effort to parse, review and modify regexes. So basically it is a maintainability thing.

Comment: @codeakean Agreed. Just because Regexp CAN, doesn't mean it SHOULD.

Comment: I suspect you would have a very opposite view if you stopped avoiding them. @Ohgodwhy that is nonsense, you always use the best tool for the job. 20+ lines of code for this is ridiculous.

Comment: @rjdown I'm sorry, but I disagree. Lengthy code does not mean that the code is bad. Please show me how you're going to handle error reporting with 1 line of RegExp and I'll concede.

Comment: @rjdown I am not avoiding them, I used one in an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684064/php-get-array-of-search-terms-from-string/26684450#26684450) as late as today. I am just conservative in my use.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy code is always bad if it can easily be done more efficiently. If you need error reporting in your code to check regexes, you're doing it wrong. Try this http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I offer a different solution, mainly because regexp provides little error reporting, and you would have to manually test the string afterwards anywhay for cohesion. Consider breaking the patterns apart and adding their own error. Iterate each of the requirements, and test the pattern. Push errors into an array and check after for their existence. Return a predeclared variable as true/false for the purpose of validating using `if(validate_password($pass)):`. Here's the mockup:

```
function validate_password($pass){
    $requirements = array();

    //uppercase
    $requirements['uppercase']['pattern'] = '/[A-Z]/';
    $requirements['uppercase']['error'] = 'Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter.';

    //lowercase
    $requirements['lowercase']['pattern'] = '/[a-z]/';
    $requirements['lowercase']['error'] = 'Your password must contain at least one lowercase letter.';

    //requires a number
    $requirements['number']['pattern'] = '/[0-9]/';
    $requirements['number']['error'] = 'Your password must contain at least one number.';

    //special characters
    $requirements['special_character']['pattern'] = '/[!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+{};\:,<\.>]/';
    $requirements['special_character']['error'] = 'Your password must contain at least one special character.';

    //length
    $requirements['length']['pattern'] = '/^.{8,}/';
    $requirements['length']['error'] = 'Your password must be at least 8 characters in length total.';



    $is_valid = false; //our flag to return as true once all tests have passed.
    $errors = false;

    //validate all requirements
    foreach($requirements as $idx => $req):
        if(preg_match($req['pattern'], $pass, $matches)):
            $is_valid = true;
        else:
            $errors[] = $req['error'];
            $is_valid = false;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    //if we had errors above
    if($errors):
        $is_valid = false;
        foreach($errors as $error):
            echo '<p>', $error, '</p>';
        endforeach;

    endif;
    return $is_valid;
}
$pass = 'j!Adz6'; //change this to test
echo validate_password($pass);
```

And an [eval.in](https://eval.in/215647) example for your pleasure.